# array insertion l-value,r-values

Tags: c++, arrays

This is just out of curiosity, while i was practicing array inserting for fun.
The question is in the below code why `a[i]=a[i+1]` giving me some garbage value but setting it to `a[i+1]=a[i]` solves the problem. Logically they do the same , but I just wanted to know weather it has something to do with l-value and r-value references?

```
#include<iostream>
    
#include<array>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pos,value;      
    std::array<int,10> arr{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (int i:arr){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    cin>>value>>pos;
    for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=pos;i--){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[pos]=value;
    for (int i:arr){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }

}
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pos,value;      
    std::array<int,10> arr{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (int i:arr){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    cin>>value>>pos;
    for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=pos;i--){
        arr[i+1]=arr[i];
    }
    arr[pos]=value;
    for (int i:arr){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr[i+1]` is out-of-range for `i=arr.size()-1`.

Comment: Your "fix" can write out of bounds of the array, and you're just not seeing the mistake in the terminal printout.

Comment: @sweenish i don't get what you mean bro, now I've edited the code .Is it fine now??

Comment: There is no difference between the two code snippets (except a blank line) and `a[i+1]=a[i]` isn't used in any of them.

Comment: And you haven't fixed the out-of-range problem. You start `i=arr.size()` and access both `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` - both are out of bounds.

Comment: @shyam0x You didn't fix it, you made it even worse. `arr[i+1]` is now 2 steps out of bounds for `i = arr.size()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo accidently copied the same code:( my bad

Comment: Why do you say "logically they do the same"? They both invoke undefined behavior and therefore any program behavior is exactly as valid for both versions of the code as any other program behavior, I suppose. `a[i] = a[i+1]` reads from `a[i+1]` and writes to `a[i]`. `a[i+1] = a[i]` reads from `a[i]` and writes to `a[i+1]`. Since `a[i+1]` is out of bounds of your array when `i = arr.size()-1`, that means reading from it and writing to it are both UB. However, the UB only happens to be visible in the `a[i] = a[i+1]` case, because your loop to print values correctly stays in bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Logically they do the same*"

No - the first version fills the affected part of the array with the same number (the last one in the array). The second shuffles numbers upwards to leave room for `value`.

Do the loop manually with pen and paper and you'll see that the first version copies the same value down until `pos`.

You also start both loops by accessing `arr` out of bounds which makes both versions having *undefined behavior*.

I suspect you want the version shuffling numbers upwards:

```
for(int i=arr.size()-2; i>=pos; --i) { // -2 since i+1 must be less than size()
    arr[i+1]=arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have anything to do with l- and r-value references.

Here, over the first iteration, `arr[i+1]` goes out of bounds. Also, since the edit you made, `arr[i]` would also go out of bounds.

```
for(int i=arr.size();i>=pos;i--){
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
}
```

`arr.size()` returns the number of elements. Remember, in c++, indexing starts from `0`, so the index to the last value would always be `arr.size()-1`.